# New vanity, supply lines coming from side wall

Tags: plumbing, vanity

I am installing a new double sink vanity in a bathroom. The drain is in an exterior wall behind the spot where the vanity goes, but the house was replumbed at some point and the water supply lines were moved to an interior wall at the side of the vanity. The rear exterior wall is cinder block with furring strips and insulation, rather than just drywall and 2x4s, so presumably it was much easier to run the new lines through the interior wall on the side. In general that wouldn't be a problem, but in the corner where the pipes come through, there is a load-bearing 2x4 that the pipes are attached to, causing a 1" to 1-1/2" gap between the pipes and the rear wall, like this.[image: water supply pipes from side interior wall]

This creates a problem because I'd like the vanity to be against the wall, but with the pipes like this, I can't do that because the pipes are too far out to run behind the vanity. That leaves me with drilling holes in the side of the vanity, which isn't necessarily a problem, except for the fact that the pipes line up with one of the 2" thick vanity legs rather than the thin panel on the side.

[image: pipe distance from wall]

[image: thickness of vanity leg]

I've thought of a few ways to get around the problem, but I think I've run into "analysis paralysis" where I'm not confident in any of the ideas. Drilling holes in the leg makes me think I'll be compromising the main supports for the marble vanity top, putting in elbows to reroute the pipes against the wall or so they come out even further seems risky because I'd be adding additional points of failure to the pipes (they're CPVC), and I'm hesitant to reroute the pipes altogether because I literally just finished redoing the drywall, texture, primer, and paint in this room, so I'd essentially be destroying a portion of that work.

What would you do in this situation?

Edit:
More pictures of vanity for purposes of demonstrating materials.

[image: vanity corner]
[image: vanity front]
[image: vanity angle]

Currently I'm not home or else I would take more pictures, but I figured these that I had already might give an idea regarding materials and workmanship of vanity. It's by Joss and Main if that helps. As far as I can tell, it's solid wood for the legs and 3/4" plywood for the top, under the marble, so that leads me to believe it's pretty well made (as opposed to cheap particle-board). It weighs about 400 pounds.

Comment: One reason it was replumbed was those pipes froze and leaked/flooded.  Most studs/joists are allowed ~40% holes, so maybe better pictures of the legs plus material will help.

Comment: Sort of - I'm in Florida so I don't think they froze, but most houses around here have been replumbed because the original copper pipes are from the 60's, so they probably sprung a leak somewhere and they just redid the whole plumbing system. Common practice here in Florida is to replumb through the attic, because we don't have basements. That means you have to fight with fishing pipes down through the wall, and it's just easier to avoid furring strips and all that stuff.

Comment: Those legs look big enough to handle a notch/hole.  Just make sure your measurements are done right/measure twice cut once, so the notch/hole is just big enough to pass though.

Comment: Sounds like a plan to me - that was my first thought and certainly follows the KISS principal. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you're worried about structural issues, worst case, since that side is against the wall, you can glue and screw a strut on the inside or outside of the cabinet wall.  You're lucky that there's no wall on the right side of the vanity, and you can just shift the vanity to the left over the supply pipe!

Answer (score 0):

As crip659 suggested, drilling two holes through the rear leg should be the simplest solution and isn't likely to compromise the leg due to the small size of the holes. The vanity will also be fastened to the wall, so that should make up for any weakness introduced by the holes, if any.